# how to detect changes in database from jsf web application

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf

i have  just completed a jsf application and ready to deploy,but ran into some issues. My application has a table with each row representing an employee.Now i have indicated a resume/suspend status links with jquery indicating if an any action can be performed on the employee(resume) or no action can be performed on the employee(suspend).This functionality i implemented with jquery,because i didn't want a page refresh tampering with these links.Now a scenerio presents itself, assuming the link initially displays suspend indicating that pressing it ,suspends the employee and displays resume.Now imagine 2 users one presses the link which changes, but the other sees the initial link value.Things get really messy when this other person presses this link which changes database value.All i want now is find a way for the application to detect the changes in the database caused by pressing the suspend/resume links and automatically write these changes so that the links value change elsewhere in web application table automatically without a page refresh

Comment: You should use a poll component like [PrimeFaces Polling](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/poll.jsf) or [RichFaces Polling](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=poll)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read and try out more about Server Side Push mechanisms in-order to find a solution to this issue. A Javascript/JQuery AJAX polling technique can be used to retrieve the updated data from server from time to time. Most JSF Component libraries have this feature integrated into their libraries you may use it to your liking. There's also Comet/bayeux as a technology which you can use but its a bit complex. This link is a good starting point which you can start on...

http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery